# Adjust text in a table

Tags: tables

I want the positions of texts in the last row (2\pi and 4\pi) to be in the middle of the row. Everything else is fine and should be kept unchanged.

[image]

```
\usepackage{array,bm,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{table}
\caption{Comparisons between the 0-$\pi$ qubit and the non-compact transmon/CPB.}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|P{3.5cm}|P{2.2cm}|P{2.2cm}|}
    \hline
     & \textbf{Qubit potential periodicity}          & \textbf{Gate potential periodicity} \\ \hline
    \textbf{The 0-}$\bm{\pi}$ \textbf{qubit [7,18]}                 & $\pi$ & $2\pi$   \\ \hline
    \textbf{The non-compact transmon/CPB}                      &  $2\pi$  & $4\pi$   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:compare}
  \end{table}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: try `m` instead of `p` in second line above code as `m{#1}`

Comment: In case the answer meets your requirement please tick the check mark on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m` will vertically center the contents of the cell/column

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  

\usepackage{array,bm,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}  

\begin{table}
\caption{Comparisons between the 0-$\pi$ qubit and the non-compact transmon/CPB.}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|P{3.5cm}|P{2.2cm}|P{2.2cm}|}
    \hline
     & \textbf{Qubit potential periodicity}          & \textbf{Gate potential periodicity} \\ \hline
    \textbf{The 0-}$\bm{\pi}$ \textbf{qubit [7,18]}                 & $\pi$ & $2\pi$   \\ \hline
    \textbf{The non-compact transmon/CPB}                      &  $2\pi$  & $4\pi$   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:compare}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Some prettifying added

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparisons between the 0-$\pi$ qubit and the non-compact transmon/CPB.}
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}{P{3.5cm}P{2.2cm}P{2.2cm}}
    \hline
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Potential periodicity}}\\ \cline{2-3} 
     & \textbf{Qubit}          & \textbf{Gate} \\ \hline
    \textbf{The 0-}$\bm{\pi}$ \textbf{qubit [7,18]} & $\pi$ & $2\pi$   \\ \hline
    \textbf{The non-compact transmon/CPB}           &  $2\pi$  & $4\pi$   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:compare}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.